# show a picture with windows photoviewer and be able navigate to next photo

Tags: c#, windows, image, photo, photoviewer

How is it possible to show a photo with Windows photoviewer and be able to navigate forward and backward to the other photos in the directory.

At the moment ich just call the assigned application

```
var fileNameComplete = @"C:\Temp\sample_photo.png";
Process.Start(fileNameComplete);
```

and this opens MS photo (in my case), but I am not able to navigate foward and backward to the other pictures in the directory.

Comment: Do you want to navigate programatically ?

Answer (score 1):

You must give the `executable file of picture viewer` as a FileName parameter to the process:

```
Process photoViewer = new Process();

//executable file of picture viewer
photoViewer.StartInfo.FileName = @"F:\Google.Picasa\Picasa3\Picasa3.exe";
photoViewer.StartInfo.Arguments =ImagePathString;
photoViewer.Start();
```

Comment: And how to start MS photo? It is a UWP app as far as i know...
I know that i have to start it this way, but I need the path and the parameters (did not find them on the MS homepage)